# Is this area a proper visualisation of the heat and internal energy change in a $P,V$-diagram?

Tags: thermodynamics

The area under the curve in a $P,V$ diagram is the $W$ work done by the system, i.e.:
[image]

Where the yellow area is the work done by the system in going from point A to B.
The internal energy of an ideal gas is:

$$E = \frac{3}{2}nRT = \frac{3}{2}PV$$
Since $PV$ is the rectangular area made by the point and the axes, it seems you can visualise the internal energy of a system like so:

[image]

So if you go from point A to B the change in internal energy $\Delta E$ is proportional to the orange area, i.e. $\frac{3}{2}(E_B - E_A)$

However since $$ \frac{3}{2} \text{Area} = \Delta E, \frac{1}{2} \text{Area} = W$$
$$ \frac{3}{2} \text{Area} - \frac{1}{2} \text{Area} = \text{Area}  = Q (?)$$

[image]

The calculation is $$\Delta Q=\Delta E+\Delta W=\frac{3}{2}\left(P_BV_B-P_AV_A\right)-P_A\left(V_B-V_A\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(V_B-V_A\right)\left(P_B-P_A\right)$$

EDIT (15/5):

With the help of Sabat Anwar I think I found the answer which is the following:

[image]

Writing it out it:

$$ \Delta E = Q - W $$
$$ A + B = (2A + B) - A $$

Comment: Why are the last two terms for work in your last equation negative? Also, your second diagram has 2/3 whereas it should be 3/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E = \frac{3}{2}nRT = \frac{3}{2}PV$$

The above relation is valid only for mono-atomic gases. But let us assume that we are talking about monoatomic gas only and proceed through your argument. I am also assuming that we are considering expansion.

We will use following figure. It is similar to your figure but names of areas are slightly different.

[image]

As per my figure, $\Delta E = \frac{3}{2}(A2 + A3)$

This matches your equation. However I have named the 'orange area' in your figure.

Coming to Work, $W = A2$. You have written that $W = \frac{1}{2}Area$. That is not necessarily true. That would require $A2 = A3$

We can calculate Q by using $Q = \Delta E + W$. However the result will not match your result because of above mistakes.
$$Q = 2*A2 + A3$$

Comment: Thank you very much! That is very clear. I made the mistake of assuming that the slope of the line $ \frac{P}{V} = 1 $ which obviously doesn't need to be. However It seems that is possible to get visual insight to the heat gained or lost given your formula $Q = 2* A2 + A3$. Is this generalisable to a closed loop, where the enclosed area is the work? Will the heat gained be twice the enclosed area and the area to the $P$ axis?